# Netsh batch file, wont remember the gateway

Tags: batch, ipv4, gateway, netsh

I'm making a little batch file to change some network adapter settings:

Can anyone please explain why this works:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.1.11 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1
```

However this doesn't (It amends the IP, SUBNET however it makes no changes to the Gateway):

```
set /p FIRSTIP=Please type the IP address provided: 
set /p SUBNETIP=Please type the Subnet IP provided: 
set /p DFTGATEWAY=Please type the Gateway provided: 

netsh interface ipv4 set address name="Local Area Connection" static %FIRSTIP% %SUBNETIP% %GATEWAY%
```

This is on a Windows 10 machine.
I've been scratching my head at this one and most KB articles seem of little help.

Comment: DFTGATEWAY is not the same variable as GATEWAY

Comment: In the future, to troubleshoot things like this you can just use `ECHO ON`, or put `ECHO ` in front of the line that's causing problems

Comment: @BenVoigt how did I not noticed that!!! Thank you ever so much :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because finding a typo is unlikely to ever be interesting to future readers.